# Linux, Curl, send a -X POST without xml file

Tags: xml, linux, curl

I have a little sh script in Linux for an -X POST with curl:

```
curl -X POST http://serverip:8081/WebServices/WebServiceSQLTestresult.svc?wsdl -H "Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"" -H "SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/IWebServiceSQLTestresult/InsertPruefResultatFromXMLFile"" --data @\u\ManInTheMiddle.xml  | grep -o 'true\|false'
```

this works fine but i have to write first the ManInTheMiddle.xml and as second step i can send the curl command.

ManInTheMiddle.xml

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <Body>
        <InsertPruefResultatFromXMLFile xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <FilePath>\\serverip\script.xml</FilePath>
        </InsertPruefResultatFromXMLFile>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

is there a way to do this without the xml file? send direct the "\serverip\script.xml"

like:

```
curl -X POST http://serverip:8081/WebServices/WebServiceSQLTestresult.svc?wsdl -H "Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"" -H "SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/IWebServiceSQLTestresult/InsertPruefResultatFromXMLFile"" --d "\\serverip\script.xml"  | grep -o 'true\|false'
```

any ideas?

EDIT1:
I just want to handle the intermediate step with the ManInTheMiddle.xml so that the server gets directly the link to the import file (\serverip\script.xml).

EDIT2:
with python it works:

```
url = "http://serverip/WebServices/WebServiceSQLTestresult.svc?wsdl"

import suds
import suds.client
client = suds.client.Client(url)
result = client.service.InsertPruefResultatFromXMLFile("\\\\serverip\script.xml")
```

thank you...

Comment: You are asking if you can send the `\\serverip\script.xml` directly, instead of sending a request to ask the service to load that file from a windows shared folder using the `\\serverip\script.xml`  syntax. But we don't know anything about the `http://serverip:8081/WebServices/WebServiceSQLTestresult.svc?wsdl` service, so that is impossible to answer. You need to go and talk to the people that wrote this web service and ask them - we have no clue how that service works.

Comment: ok so i understand the curl a little bit more... thank you ... 
I thought if file or link is the same for the server.

Answer (score 0):

Use @ before filename path:

```
curl -X POST http://serverip:8081/WebServices/WebServiceSQLTestresult.svc?wsdl -H "Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"" -H "SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/IWebServiceSQLTestresult/InsertPruefResultatFromXMLFile"" -d @"\\serverip\script.xml"  | grep -o 'true\|false'
```

Answer (score 0):

$() to the rescue, replace

```
--data @\u\ManInTheMiddle.xml
```

with

```
--data-raw "$(curl --silent \\serverip\script.xml)"
```

something like

```
curl -X POST http://serverip:8081/WebServices/WebServiceSQLTestresult.svc?wsdl -H "Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"" -H "SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/IWebServiceSQLTestresult/InsertPruefResultatFromXMLFile"" --data-raw "$(curl --silent \\serverip\script.xml)"  | grep -o 'true\|false'
```

note that idk how portable $() is, it certainly wouldn't work on microsoft's cmd.exe for instance, but at least it'll work on bash